# How to tilt the label of plot in R

Tags: r

I have some data with 25 categories and when i plotted the data using `barchartGC`
it looked like 
[image]

Is there any way I can tilt the X-axis text so I can read the values of Categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean with 'tilt', but here is how you could make it more readable.
As `barchartGC` is just a wrapper for `lattice` `barchart`, you are supposed to be able to use any arguments for `barchart`.
For instance, you could rotate your x-legend by adding this argument to your `barchartGC` call :

```
scales=list(x=list(rot=45, labels=your_labels))
```

Comment: Thank you, by tilt i meant rotating 45 degree. It worked fine.